# cordova bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired does not emit values in android 10

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth, ionic-native

We recently bought a new samsung galaxy tab A7 with android 10 and wanted to test our ionic 5 app which uses [cordova bluetooth serial plugin](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial) and [ionic's wrapper](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial).

The `bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired` Method does not resolve and emit any values anymore. Location permission is granted. Does anyone has a fix or workaround for android 10?

```
    public scanForBluetoothDevices$(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.enableBluetooth$().pipe(
            switchMap(() => {
                this.unpairedIsLoading$.next(true);
                this.pairedIsLoading$.next(true);
                return from(this.bluetoothSerial.list()).pipe(
                    switchMap(paired => {
                        console.log('paired', paired);
                        this.pairedIsLoading$.next(false);
                        this.setPairedDevicesList(this.selectUniqDevicesByAddress(paired));
                        return this.bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired();
                    }),
                    map(unpaired => {
                        console.log('unpaired', unpaired);
                        this.unpairedIsLoading$.next(false);
                        this.setUnpairedDevicesList(this.selectUniqDevicesByAddress(unpaired));
                        return true;
                    })
                );
            })
        );
    }
```